# Unity ios parse push notification not recieving after publish

Tags: ios, parse-platform, notifications, push

I developed game on Unity and integrated parse push notification in it.
It worked fine before publish to app store.

After publishing, push notification stoped work.

Which certificate I have to upload into parse concole?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you upload a production push certificate on parse ? Did you try using push with an ad-hoc provisioning profile, in order to test push in distribution ?

Comment: Yes, I uploaded production push certificate on parse. Yes, ad-hoc worked fine.

Comment: Erf, it's often the main issue found in this case. I'm sorry for being unable to help you further, try looking for the parse troubleshooting guide https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#push-notifications

Comment: Is this normal, that certificate is Development? http://prntscr.com/a79hqj Should it be distribution or else?

Comment: I've just uploaded a test production certificate on Parse and it's considered as Production one : http://prntscr.com/a79lmn . Your issue should come from here.

Comment: I have to certificates: http://prntscr.com/a79n0z When I exporte .p12 I get Development both. What is my error?

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED!

Just create certificate not from Identifiers->appid->app, but from certificates->production->create and it works fine.

Comment: I didn't know you could create certificate directly from the app-id page ! So the `Production SSL Certificate` is bugging from app-id page ?  You should mark your answer as accepted by the way ;)